How to include created Geometry Nodes in addon?
I created Geometry Nodes group that I want to include with my addon so I can use it with other projects and/or share it with someone. How can I link Geometry Nodes to my addon?

You can convert it to python and dynamically generate it in your addon https://github.com/BrendanParmer/NodeToPython

You can bundle blend files in your addon zip files and append elements from it
